# How to count occurrences of customer behavior happening on same day?

Tags: sql

I've got a sql related I've been trying to figure out.. There is a table of customer data with two types of interactions (dif columns) and corresponding date. I've pivoted the table so instead the data looks like the following:

| id (int) | event text/boolean (1 or 0) | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021/10/1 |
| 1 | 0 | 2021/10/1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021/9/26 |
| 2 | 0 | 2021/9/24 |

etc .. What I am trying to do is count the number of occurrences where there is a 1 and 0 event on the same date, total for all customers. Maybe even counting within a date range would be useful.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general approach would be:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT date
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE event IN (0, 1)   -- can add date range here
    GROUP BY date
    HAVING MIN(event) <> MAX(event)
) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so simple! I was originally doing another query using CTE and trying to do build off that had me way overcomplicating things ..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum` with `group by`:

```
with cte(date, pos, neg) as (
    select date, sum(event = 1), sum(event = 0) from events group by date
)
select * from cte where pos > 0 and neg > 0;
```

Edit: without a `cte`:

```
select * from (select date, sum(event = 1) pos, sum(event = 0) neg from events group by date) 
where pos > 0 and neg > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. I originally used CTE to do another query so I was trying to do the next step using CTE, but the other answer was simpler/cut out a step..

Comment: @NickC Please see my recent edit, I added a version that does not use the `cte`.